# Reference for inserted element through execCommand (insertContent) in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I need a reference for the element which i have inserted in TinyMCE editor through

```
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="marker">my_node_content</span>')
```

OR, Is there any workaround to insert element at cursor index other than `execCommand` in TinyMCE editor?

So that, I can retain the reference to inserted element.