# Insert element using TinyMCE execCommand and retain a reference

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

When using TinyMCE4, you can insert content at the cursor using

```
.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content')
```

I need to insert content but retain a reference to said content. I have tried

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, div);
```

but tinyMCE throws an error. The question has been asked a few places, but never received a single response. For example

[Reference for inserted element through execCommand (insertContent) in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547715/reference-for-inserted-element-through-execcommand-insertcontent-in-tinymce)

and

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=35214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way:

```
var span = tinymce.activeEditor.getDoc().createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('id', 'test');
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, span.outerHTML);
var my_elem = tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().querySelector('#test');
console.log('my_elem', my_elem);
```

If needed remove the id attribute afterwards (you could also use a class attribute or anything else).